# How does the contents of jquery ui tab body gets Changed On clicking tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery ui Vertical Tab which is working fine but i need to use it in my way and requirement.
For the same i have to know how the Contents of the jquery ui tab body (With Body i mean the portion where Content of A, B etc are getting displayed in the fiddle) is getting changed .What and how to change the contents there with my DIV and Other HTML fields..

Here is the Script that has been used to handle that but i am not getting how this is changing the contents..

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    window.onload = function () {
        $('#tabs')
.tabs()
.addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');

    }//]]>  

</script>
```

and here is the Fiddle link..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/nn2Qw/)

Please help me to resolve the issue..Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier(s) you are looking for is `#tabs` & `.ui-tabs-nav`

Just set your desired height by css:

```
#tabs {
    height: 500px !important;
}

.ui-tabs-nav {
    height: 496px !important;
}
```

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nn2Qw/3767/)

---

And by increasing height, I guess you want to fill the empty space with more tabs. Easily done:

```
<li><a href="#e">Tab E</a></li>
```

```
<div id="e">Content of E</div>
```

[**Updated JsFiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/nn2Qw/3772/)

Comment: Thanks ..It Solved my first problem ..Now how the contents of the body is getting changed...Please read my Post Once again .I have updated my post ..

Answer (score 0):

To change the default height of your tab, edit the top/bottom padding in this rule:

```
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.6em 1em; // edit 0.6em to whatever you need
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn2Qw/3768/

As for your other question, the property `aria-controls` in each `li`, controls what content is shown.

Comment: Thanks ..It Solved my first problem ..Now how the contents of the body is getting changed...Please read my Post Once again .I have updated my post ..